# C# error: Use of unassigned local variable 'datePicker1'

Tags: c#

So i am trying to make an app that counts the days since you were born, i have to use a datepicker to input a birthdate. My problem is that it keeps saying "Use of unassigned local variable 'datePicker1'
can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        DateTime datePicker1 = datePicker1.Date;<--- This is where it says that it's wrong
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan Days = (localDate - datePicker1);
        var button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        button1.Click += (e, o) => 

        {

            textView1.Text = "you are living for " + Days + " days";

        };




    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well yes - you're trying to declare a local variable called `datePicker1` and initialize it using itself. Perhaps you meant `DateTime date = datePicker1.Date;` to use a field instead?

Comment: i tried to do that, but it didn't work. It now says: datePicker1 does not exist in current context

Comment: Well do you *have* a date picker? Perhaps you should be using `FindViewById` to get the date picker?

Answer (score 1):

You are using same identifier in DateTime and DatePicker

---

Change this line

```
DateTime datePicker1 = datePicker1.Date;
```

To

```
DateTime datePicker1_Value = datePicker1.Date;
```

---

And change this

```
TimeSpan Days = (localDate - datePicker1);
```

To

```
TimeSpan Days = (localDate - datePicker1_Value);
```

---

You can use another name instead of "datePicker1_Value", the only point is that the identifier must be different from "datePicker1"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your XAML is correct here.

You need to have an event handler on your DatePicker. If someone changes the value then only you may want to calculate.

e.g.

```
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender,
        SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var picker = sender as DatePicker;


    (picker.SelectedDate?? DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Two more questions:
What do those questionmarks in your answer mean and where am I supposed to place the code in your answer?

Comment: @F.W. Cannot give you the exact code as I don't have Xamrin installed - ?. is C#6 feature you don't have to use it, you can just check if null instead.  you need to have an event hooked into XAML<... x:Name="fromDatePicker" DateSelected="OnDateSelected" />

Comment: @codebased nIn fact, you should not use `??` in this case as time could be updated between 2 calls to `DateTime.Now` and cause small value for the difference instead of 0.